# How to make emacs configurable for julia-lang

Tags: macos, emacs, julia

I want to use emacs for julia language. Let me explain myself. First of all, I'm using OsX Yosemite. As you know, when you write a python function, emacs will highlight python-specific syntax for you automatically. Similarly, I want from emacs to do it for julia programming language. For this, I've follow the written steps in [this](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia) github repo.

1) First of all, I've clone that repository into my mac, (Under `~/myLaptop/Documents/ESS`

2) I made `cd` into cloned git directory(`Documents/ESS`) and run `make all`

3) now at this point, in the github repository, it is said that

> Load ess-site.el in your .emacs and, unless your julia (julia-basic
>   for older versions) is already in exec path, set
>   inferior-ess-julia-program-name to point to julia executable:
>
> (load "path/to/ESS/git/lisp/ess-site")

I could not understand this part. Now what should I do ? 
this is view of my `.emacs.d` directory

```
xxxs-MacBook-Air:.emacs.d xxx$ ls
auto-save-list
xxxs-MacBook-Air:.emacs.d xxx$
```

this is the ESS directory :

```
xxxs-MacBook-Air:ESS xxx$ ls
ANNOUNCE        NEWS            VERSION         install-sh
COPYING         ONEWS           debian          lisp
ChangeLog       OONEWS          doc         mkinstalldirs
LDA         README          ess-autoloads.el    rsn.txt
Makeconf        README.md       etc         test
Makefile        RPM.spec.in     fontlock-test
xxxs-MacBook-Air:ESS xxx$
```

Lastly, here is my emacs version

```
xxxs-MacBook-Air:~ xxx$ emacs -version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
```

This is the first time I'll use emacs and therefore please explain me like I'm emacs dummy. Thanks in advance, I hope I provice all the required information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd point is telling you to add that code to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). This is like `juliarc` or `vimrc` on which you want to tell the program (Emacs, in this case) what to execute every time it opens.

The `set inferior-ess-julia-program-name` stuff will be needed in case the `julia` command is not in your path.

How do you know if it's not in your path?
Try:

```
xxxs-MacBook-Air:~ xxx$ which julia
```

If that returns an error, and, let's say, you have the julia binary at `/home/user/stuff/julia/bin/julia` then you have to edit your init file and add:

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(inferior-ess-julia-program-name "/home/user/stuff/julia/bin/julia"))
```

IIRC, you can also run `M-x customize-variable RET inferior-ess-julia-program-name`
(btw, I use `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as my init file)